# SMTP connection failed - gives error 535 joomla

Tags: php, email, joomla, smtp

I have upgraded the Joomla version of my project from 3.0.3 to 3.3.3. I could send the mail in previous version of joomla. Now after I upgraded it returns an error SMTP Connection failed.

For joomla 3.3.3 i have configured same SMTP settings on my localhost, and I have done the same on the actual hosting. With localhost I'm able to send the mail but not from the server.

Comment: Still having the error on 3.3.6? Check with your host to make sure the firewall isn't blocking the port you're trying to use.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gmail? Have you changed your password recently on Gmail? If you did, then make sure that you have changed in the SMTP settings as well and be patient a bit as sometimes this change can take some time to propagate to all servers. Note that the smtp port for Gmail is 25.

If you're not using Gmail, then double and triple check your password as well as the SMTP port.